# Parsing specific values with python and TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, text-parsing

I'm stuck with this task, and I seem to not be able to crack the code. My intention is to parse text, containing lines formatted like this:

```
date time number
```

and I want to make some simple statistics with it.

The tricky thing is to make a system that will create a list of `int`s with only the highest "number" on any given date.

i.e. given the following:

**followerNum.txt**

```
2018-06-11 12:29 692
2018-06-11 12:55 690
2018-06-11 13:00 690
2018-06-11 14:40 690
2018-06-11 15:01 690 <-- this one
2018-06-12 06:00 687
2018-06-12 09:27 688
2018-06-12 09:30 688
2018-06-12 09:37 688
2018-06-12 09:48 688
2018-06-12 10:08 688 <-- this one
2018-06-13 06:00 699
2018-06-13 08:06 700
2018-06-13 10:34 702
2018-06-13 10:40 702 <-- this one
2018-06-14 06:00 709 <-- this one
2018-06-15 06:57 719 <-- this one
2018-06-16 07:50 721 <-- this one
```

So in this case, the list would contain `690, 688, 702, 709, 719, 721`.

I've been back and forth with this for a while, and now I'm just empty of options. Also, I want that each time that the code runs, it makes the new list with the current data from the file, and I seem to be able to make a loop for it.

This is how far I've got:

```
#open the file and create a list with the lines:

file = open("followerNum.txt").read().splitlines()

#get the first and last 'words' of the first line

date,b,folnum= file[0].split(" ")

#get the first and last 'words' of the second line

date2,b,folnum2 = file[1].split(" ")
#check if it worked
print(date, date2)

for i in file:

  if date2 == date:   #If both are equal, then replace it 
    folnum= file[i].split(" ",-1)
  else:               if not, append 
    folnum.append(file[i].split(" ",-1))
```

And when I run it I get:

```
folnum= file[i].split(" ",-1)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Well, I hope you can see the noob fails here, also how would you have done it? Would be cool to see as I'm a self-tought newbie :)

Comment: `i` is a line already, *not an index*. Python `for` loops are *for each loops*, meaning that the actual values in `file` are being iterated over. Use `i.split(...)`.

Comment: thanks all for the help, Ill try now again :) I was drowned but now I see there is a lot to learn

Comment: If you want the highest number on each date, then the number for 2018-06-11 should be 692, not 690.

Answer (score 0):

here :

```
folnum= file[i].split(" ",-1)
```

when you make a for loop statment `i` is of type `str` not `int`

```
for i in file: # i is of type string not integer
    # in this case you has something like this
    file['a'].split(' ', -1) # ['a'] is for example,
```

in this case when we call `lst['string']` we get

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

you need to check first of all what you have in `i` variable, also as mentioned @MartijnPieters you can use `i.split()`

```
lines = open("demo.txt").read().splitlines()
...
for line in lines:
    ...
    line.split(' ', -1)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for i in file:
```

to

```
for i, line in enumerate(file):
```

That way, i will be an integer index rather than a string.  Line is the string.

Answer (score 0):

Split the contents of the file and convert into a dict; On python 3.6 and greater, you would have only the last entry present in the dict

```
>>> data="""
... 2018-06-11 12:29 692
... 2018-06-11 12:55 690
... 2018-06-11 13:00 690
... 2018-06-11 14:40 690
... 2018-06-11 15:01 690 <-- this one
... 2018-06-12 06:00 687
... 2018-06-12 09:27 688
... 2018-06-12 09:30 688
... 2018-06-12 09:37 688
... 2018-06-12 09:48 688
... 2018-06-12 10:08 688 <-- this one
... 2018-06-13 06:00 699
... 2018-06-13 08:06 700
... 2018-06-13 10:34 702
... 2018-06-13 10:40 702 <-- this one
... 2018-06-14 06:00 709 <-- this one
... 2018-06-15 06:57 719 <-- this one
... 2018-06-16 07:50 721 <-- this one
... """

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> new_d = dict(d.split(' ', 1) for d in data.strip().splitlines())
>>> pprint(new_d)
{'2018-06-11': '15:01 690 <-- this one',
 '2018-06-12': '10:08 688 <-- this one',
 '2018-06-13': '10:40 702 <-- this one',
 '2018-06-14': '06:00 709 <-- this one',
 '2018-06-15': '06:57 719 <-- this one',
 '2018-06-16': '07:50 721 <-- this one'}
>>>
```

**Edit**

If you want only the 3rd field

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> indexer = itemgetter(0,2)
>>> new_d = dict(indexer(d.split(' ', 3)) for d in data.strip().splitlines())
>>> pprint(new_d)
{'2018-06-11': '690',
 '2018-06-12': '688',
 '2018-06-13': '702',
 '2018-06-14': '709',
 '2018-06-15': '719',
 '2018-06-16': '721'}
>>>
```

For getting this working in python version less than 3.6, use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict as odict
>>> new_d = dict(indexer(d.split(' ', 3)) for d in data.strip().splitlines())
>>> pprint(new_d)
OrderedDict([('2018-06-11', '690'),
             ('2018-06-12', '688'),
             ('2018-06-13', '702'),
             ('2018-06-14', '709'),
             ('2018-06-15', '719'),
             ('2018-06-16', '721')])
```

Comment: how would you get only the last digits, ignoring the time stamps?

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: I managed to make a listto do some dataanalisys with it, and to my surprise, i found that the items are scrambled in order... i defenitelly fail to see how this happened, all i find is that dictionaries have no order. so, well perhaps the way i found to transform the values  of the dict into a list scrambled the order, which let me to the question, how would you do that so the values of the new list appear in order with the date? im sorry, i ussually find my way through things but this is really giving me a headache..

Comment: dict output: {'2018-06-16': '725', '2018-06-11': '690', '2018-06-15': '719', '2018-06-14': '709', '2018-06-12': '688', '2018-06-13': '702'}

Comment: As I had mentioned, this code would work only from python 3.6 and above. I have updated the answer to get it working with older version of python,

Comment: wherever you are, thank you a million for your help, really, I didnt knew there where so many pakages to import, and your sleak code is worth a "wow".

Comment: It looks like all of these return the *last* entry for each date, not the one with highest number.